# PHPickerViewController buggy UI flow in multi-select mode

Tags: ios, ios14, photokit, phpickerviewcontroller

The attached GIF says all, when using PHPickerViewController in multi-selection mode (selectionLimit = 0), the picker randomly selects assets as the user scrolls the scroll view without tapping on the photos. I am wondering how PHPickerViewController is so buggy which is still unresolved in iOS 14.2 beta 2 as well! And this is reproducible with the PHPickerDemo sample code that was part of WWDC 2020 video. I am wondering if there is a way to fix this, such as by tweaking gesture recognisers, etc.?

[image]

Comment: do you know about this [feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/selecting_multiple_items_with_a_two-finger_pan_gesture), or is it something else that you're talking about?

Comment: No, I didn't know about this but how do I disable it?

Comment: you can't disable or change the multi-select or any other feature in PHPicker unless it's included in the [PHPickerConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration)

Comment: But this is buggy, as I am scrolling down, I see a full row of photos are getting selected inadvertently!

Comment: Your best option is to ask apple to fix it or improve it but I'm not sure if they would also allow you to disable it. and by the way I'm using iOS 14.2 beta 3 since yesterday and it seems like the picker is improved for example I'm not seeing the "picker unavailable" message like before

Comment: It's improved, yes, and in some cases issue seems to be resolved. But inadvertent multi-slection is still sometimes a problem. And I already filed a bug but I receive response for only 1-2 bugs out of every 10 bugs I file.